# Advanced Custom Fields show content if no post object

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a repeater field which allows me to add different footers depending on what page is selected using the post_object field...the below code does exactly that and works the way the I want.

```
<?php global $wp_query;
        $page_id = $wp_query->post->ID;
      ?>

      <?php
        // check if the repeater field has rows of data
        if( have_rows('company','option') ):
        // loop through the rows of data
        while ( have_rows('company', 'option') ) : the_row(); // display a sub field value
          $page = get_sub_field('applies_to', 'option');
          $company_tagline = get_sub_field('company_and_tagline','option');
          $contact = get_sub_field('contact','option');
        ?>


        <?php if( $page == $page_id ) : ?>

          <div class="company-details-container">

            <?php if( get_sub_field('company_and_tagline','option') ): ?>
              <div class="company-tagline">
                <?php echo $company_tagline; ?>
                &#64; <?php echo date('Y'); ?>
              </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if( get_sub_field('contact','option') ): ?>
              <div class="company-contact">
                <span>Contact</span>
                <?php echo $contact; ?>
              </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if( get_sub_field('social','option') ): ?>
              <div class="footer-social">
                <span>Connect</span>
                <ul>
                  <?php
                    // check if the repeater field has rows of data
                    if( have_rows('social','option') ):
                    // loop through the rows of data
                    while ( have_rows('social', 'option') ) : the_row(); // display a sub field value
                    $social_link = get_sub_field('social_link', 'option');
                    $icon = get_sub_field('icon','option');
                  ?>

                  <li><a href="<?php echo $social_link; ?>"><img class="icon" src="<?php echo $icon; ?>"></a></li>

                  <?php endwhile;
                    else :
                    // no rows found
                    endif;
                  ?>
                </ul>
              </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

          </div>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endwhile;
          else :
          // no rows found
          endif;
        ?>
```

What I'm having trouble with is adding content if no page is selected via the post_object field, I'm wanting to have a default footer that will show up on all pages unless the user selects a page and includes different content for that particular footer.

When I add this:

```
<?php if(get_sub_field('applies_to', 'option')) { ?>
  <?php if( $page == $page_id ) : ?>
    <?php echo $page; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
    there is no page selected
<?php } ?>
```

This is showing the 'there is no page selected' on all pages but i want it to display on pages that have not had a page selected.

Comment: get_sub_field('applies_to', 'option') used another method  get_field('applies_to', 'option');

Comment: Thankyou but that still shows the 'there is no page selected' on every page even when a page is selected.